# Number format exceptions when reading a file in Java

Tags: java, parsing

Hey all so I'm trying to read the values from a text file so I can use it for something else- However, I keep getting a 'lava.lang.NumberFormatException' when I try to run. This is a snippet of my code and where the problem seems to lie.

```
   public void readData(String fileName) {

    try {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        String[] line;
        int mid;   //user-id
        int uid; //isbn
        int rating;  //book rating
        //int start =0;
        //String date;
        //System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        in.nextLine();
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            //if(start != 0 ){
                line = in.nextLine().split(";");
                System.out.println(line[0].trim().replace("\ufeff", "") + " length: "+  line[0].length());
                //System.out.println(line[0]+ " -----------++++++++++++++");
                mid = Integer.parseInt(line[0].trim());
                uid = Integer.parseInt(line[1].trim());  //isbn change
                rating = Integer.parseInt(line[2].trim());

                addToMovies(mid, uid, rating);
                addToCust(mid, uid, rating);
            //} //else {
                //start ++;
            }

        //}
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + fileName);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the data I'll be reading:

```
      "User-ID;""ISBN"";""Book-Rating"""
    "276725;""034545104X"";""0"""
    "276726;""0155061224"";""5"""
    "276727;""0446520802"";""0"""
    "276729;""052165615X"";""3"""
    "276729;""0521795028"";""6"""
    "276733;""2080674722"";""0"""
    "276736;""3257224281"";""8"""
    "276737;""0600570967"";""6"""
    "276744;""038550120X"";""7"""
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
    "276725 length: 7
usage: java MemReader sourceFile destFile
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""276725"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at memreader.MemReader.readData(MemReader.java:76)
at memreader.MemReader.main(MemReader.java:265)
```

It would appear that maybe java is reading invisible characters because I have tested it by printing the length of the first index and the number of characters is more than there should be. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `"”276725”` a number? I mean, how clear an exception do you want?

Comment: You are trying to parse the string `""276725"` (with the quotes!) as if it is a number. It's not; you need to remove the quotes first.

Comment: actually i was reading the file in csv format and those quotes were not there. I opened it in notepad so i could copy and paste the data.

Comment: `line[0].trim().replace("\ufeff", "")` this doesn't change the orignial content in line . Assign it back to `line[0]`, like `line[0]=line[0].trim().replace("\ufeff", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are not ignored by the parser, remove them first.

Change

```
line = in.nextLine().split(";");
```

to

```
line = in.nextLine().replaceAll("\"", "").split(";");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that seems to work. Much appreciated Carlos

Answer (score 0):

The value of `line[0]` now is **`"276725`**.

Try this.

```
mid = Integer.parseInt(line[0].substring(1).trim());
```

It will remove the leading **`"`** and the remaining value will be numeric.